# How to extract XML node values and attributes from recurring nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle

I am using Kettle and the Get Data From XML transformation to extract certain information from an XML file. I set Loop Xpath to `/*[name()='feed']/*[name()='entry']` which brings in all the relevant fields.

I would like to extract each `<region>` node from the regions node as its own field so that I can later concatenate them with a "/" delimiter.

Next, I need to create fields like `weekly_rate_from` and `weekly_rate_to` for each `<rate>` node. I can't quite figure out the Xpath to differentiate between attributes like periodType and then also extracting the from and to information as well. In other words, I need to extract only "to" and "from" rate attributes when periodType=weekly

Hopefully this isn't too confusing I'm probably not explaining well

```
<feed>
<entry>
  <content>
    <listing>    
      <regions>
        <region>World</region>
        <region>USA</region>
        <region>California</region>
        <region>Inland Empire California</region>
        <region>Temecula Valley</region>
        <region>Temecula</region>
      </regions>
      <rates rentalBasis="property">
        <rate from="3395" to="4175" currencyUnit="USD" periodType="weekly"/>
        <rate from="599" to="749" currencyUnit="USD" periodType="nightly-weekday"/>
        <rate from="799" to="1019" currencyUnit="USD" periodType="nightly-weekend"/>
      </rates>
    </listing>
  </content>
</entry>
<entry>
...
</entry>
... for a total of 20 "entry" nodes
</feed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting all region elements:

```
count(/feed/entry/content/listing/regions/region)
```

Retrieve the `from` and `to` for only periodType weekly:

```
/feed/entry/content/listing/rates/rate[@periodType = 'weekly']/@from
/feed/entry/content/listing/rates/rate[@periodType = 'weekly']/@to
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't quite brushed up on Xpath so I wasn't aware of how to get only 'weekly' attributes.